# Airflow 1.10.15. kills Zombie Tasks for seemingly no reason

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

We're using Cloud Composer (aka. Airflow) for a time now. Recently we updated to the newest version `composer-1.16.5-airflow-1.10.15`. Ever since we're experiencing some issues surrounding so called zombie tasks.

Zombie tasks seem to arise if Airflow thinks that a task is dead, therefore killing it. The decission why a task is considered dead surrounds the heartbeat of a task, some `zombie_threshold` and of course worker rescources.

Usually after around 250 seconds after a task starts it is killed of by Airflow, marking it as a zombie task. But it doesn't happen on all tasks, just on some of them.

Our task usually are triggering some Dataproc/Dataflow job, so there is really no high workload on the worker. In fact GCP is telling me I should downgrade the workers to save costs, since they are not doing much. So it seemms this is no issue.

What I tried then is to set these configurations:

```
core-store_dag_code                       = "False"
core-dagbag_import_timeout                = "180"
core-dag_file_processor_timeout           = "180"
scheduler-job_heartbeat_sec               = "5"
scheduler-scheduler_heartbeat_sec         = "5"
scheduler-scheduler_zombie_task_threshold = "600"
```

None of these settings seem to have any effect.

Does anyone know of this issue or have some idea what could help?

Comment: Does it happen for any particular task/operator? How often does it happen? Have you considered moving to Airflow 2.0?

Comment: It happens with the dataproc jobs operator and the dataflow python operator. I haven't seen this issue with the bash operator.... Airflow 2 is just a release candidate at the Google Cloud Composer environment.

Comment: But it doesn't happen on every task, just some of them. And it is somewhat random. Sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Comment: Some time ago I tried to the bug the same issue but to no avail. If your tasks are long running you can consider to split submitting the job and waiting for result into operator and sensor with reschedule mode (if you don't do it already).

Comment: That's not what I wanted to hear. Does this problem occur in Airflow 2.0?

Comment: Is there anyone else who has an idea?

Comment: How are you checking that there are zombie jobs within your environment? When did the issue started? Did this issue happened before with the same DAG?

Comment: We use Google Cloud Composer, which I updated. Ever since I have this issue with DAGs that where running fine on the old instance. The Composer prints the Zombie DAGs to the logging.

Comment: I think you should create support case if you have any package or [create a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460446&template=0) on Issue Tracker.

Comment: We run into the same problem with `composer-1.16.14-airflow-1.10.15` version. Have you found any fix for this?

Comment: Unfortunatly not. We're using Airflow 1.10.12. until Airflow 2 is out of the preview phase. I spend a great deal of time analising the problem, but couldn't come up with a solution. Sorry!